# Python XML parsing, extraction and renaming files

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.x, file, xml

I've written some code to:

1. Parse an XML file.
2. Extract some strings.
3. Make copies of the original XML whose names are suffixed with the extracted strings.

Please review this.

```
from lxml import etree as ET
import re

def create_paramsuffix_copies(xmlfile):

    NSMAP = {"c": "http://www.copasi.org/static/schema"}

    parsed = ET.parse(xmlfile)

    list_of_params = []

    for a in parsed.xpath("//c:Reaction", namespaces=NSMAP):
        for b in a.xpath(".//c:Constant", namespaces=NSMAP):
            list_of_params.append((a.attrib['name'])+'_'+(b.attrib['name']))

    return list_of_params


def add_suffix(xmlfile, name_suffix):

    parsed = ET.parse(xmlfile) #parse xml

    xmlfile = re.sub('.cps', '', xmlfile) #remove suffix

    parsed.write(xmlfile+'_'+name_suffix+'.cps', 
                 xml_declaration = True,
                 encoding = 'utf-8',
                 method = 'xml')


modelfile = 'ct.cps'

for a in create_paramsuffix_copies(modelfile):
    add_suffix(modelfile,a)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some style changes can happen, most are described [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

- Using single letter variable names can be hard to understand, and don't explain what the data is well. It is good not to use them.
- `str.format` is the best way to put variables into strings. E.G. `'{}_{}.cps'.format(xmlfile, name_suffix)`
- CONSTANTS should be all caps. `MODEL_FILE = 'ct.cps'`
- When passing 'kwargs' don't put spaces around the `=` operator. E.G. `encoding='utf-8'`
- Use new-lines sparingly.
- In-line comments are harder to read then comments before the code.
- Comments should have a space between the '#' and the comment.

---

It may be good to change `create_paramsuffix_copies` to a generator, in this case it should be faster than making a list.

```
def create_paramsuffix_copies(xmlfile):
    NSMAP = {"c": "http://www.copasi.org/static/schema"}
    parsed = ET.parse(xmlfile)
    for a in parsed.xpath("//c:Reaction", namespaces=NSMAP):
        for b in a.xpath(".//c:Constant", namespaces=NSMAP):
            yield '{}_{}'.format(a.attrib['name'], b.attrib['name'])
```

---

You could add [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to your program so people know what the functions do at a later date.

But it looks really good!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - they all sound good - I will implement them!